# How do I get the selected radio button when the radio group is inflated programmatically.

Tags: android, layout-inflater, radio-group

I have a layout that is built dynamically from a database. There are several sections, One of the pieces is a series of radio groups with custom text on each radio button that is read from the database.

My code is properly inflating the layout, adding the correct number of radio buttons and adding the correct text to them.

What I can't figure out is how to get the value of the checked radio button when it is a child of a table row. I am not using an on item selected because I need to wait until the user is sure all the answers are filled in before getting the results. So I have a separate button with an onClick that is going to read the data and store it in the database.

Here is the area in my main XML file
    
        
        
    
Here is the individual row XML

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </RadioGroup>

</TableRow>
```

Here is where I am trying to read the values of the selected radio button

```
table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout03);
for( int ii = 0; ii < nRecs3; ii++ ){   
TableRow row1= (TableRow)table.getChildAt(ii);
Log.i("radio button " , " index of row is " + String.valueOf(row1));
View child = table.getChildAt(ii);
int idx = row1.indexOfChild(child);
Log.i("radio button " , " index of child is " + String.valueOf(idx));
RadioGroup radio = (RadioGroup)child;
Log.i("radio button " , " checked button is " + String.valueOf(radio.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
            }
```

but it's crashing before it gets to the first log statement. I've tried all sorts of variations on getting the value of the child of the child row but nothing is working.

Comment: Post the logcat from the crash

Comment: I had to get the code working to collect data so rolled back to not using an inflated layout and hard coded the one radio group of interest and then getting the selected item without trying to use the child property. I am back trying to get the general case of multiple radio groups working. I am in the process of rolling my changes forward again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. For future reference in case anyone else has this issue you have to have the radiogroup be the child and then work within that to get the buttons.

Here is how I described the table in my main XML file

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll03"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="175dp">

        <TableLayout
           android:id="@+id/TableLayout03"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TableLayout>  
</ScrollView>
```

Then I have this as the XML file for the row entry:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1_lbl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:typeface="monospace" />  

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="175dp">
</RadioGroup>

</TableRow>
```

Here is the subset of code that  creates the table rows and radio groups from the database

```
    // Set up the user traits  
    cmd = String.format("select evaluation_trait_table.trait_name, evaluation_trait_table.id_traitid, " +
            "custom_evaluation_name_table.custom_eval_number " +
            "from evaluation_trait_table inner join last_eval_table on " +
            " evaluation_trait_table.id_traitid = last_eval_table.id_traitid" +
            " inner join custom_evaluation_name_table on evaluation_trait_table.id_traitid = " +
            " custom_evaluation_name_table.id_traitid where evaluation_trait_table.trait_type = 3 ") ;
    crsr = dbh.exec( cmd );
    cursor   = ( Cursor ) crsr;
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    nRecs3    = cursor.getCount(); // number of user defined traits to use
    dbh.moveToFirstRecord();
    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
        user_evaluation_traits.add(cursor.getString(0));
        user_trait_numbers.add(cursor.getInt(1));
        user_trait_number_items.add(cursor.getInt(2));              
    }
    inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout03); 
    for( int ii = 0; ii < nRecs3; ii++ ){   
        TableRow row = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.eval_custom_item, table, false);
        tempLabel = user_evaluation_traits.get(ii);
        //  Set the text for the radiogroup label
        ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1_lbl)).setText(tempLabel);
        //  Get the text for the buttons
        tempText = String.valueOf(user_trait_numbers.get(ii));
        cmd = String.format("select custom_evaluation_traits_table.custom_evaluation_item " +
                " from custom_evaluation_traits_table " +
                " where custom_evaluation_traits_table.id_traitid = '%s' "+
                " order by custom_evaluation_traits_table.custom_evaluation_order ASC ", tempText);
        crsr = dbh.exec( cmd );
        cursor   = ( Cursor ) crsr;
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        nRecs4    = cursor.getCount();
        dbh.moveToFirstRecord();                
        ArrayList buttons = new ArrayList();

        for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
            buttons.add (cursor.getString(0));
        }
        radioBtnText = (String[]) buttons.toArray(new String [buttons.size()]);
        // Build the radio buttons here
        radioGroup = ((RadioGroup) row.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1));
        addRadioButtons(user_trait_number_items.get(ii), radioBtnText);         
        table.addView(row);         
    }
```

Here is the method that creates the radiogroup

```
private void addRadioButtons(int numButtons, String[] radioBtnText) {
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < numButtons; i++){
    //instantiate...
    RadioButton radioBtn = new RadioButton(this);

    //set the values that you would otherwise hardcode in the xml...
    radioBtn.setLayoutParams 
      (new LayoutParams 
      (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    //label the button...
    radioBtn.setText(radioBtnText[i]);
    Log.i("addradiobuttons", radioBtnText[i]);
    radioBtn.setId(i);

    //add it to the group.
    radioGroup.addView(radioBtn, i);
  }
}
```

And finally the subset of code where I actually read the radio buttons and get ready to update my database

```
        table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout03);
        if (nRecs3 != 0) {
            for( int ii = 0; ii < nRecs3; ii++ ){   
                TableRow row1= (TableRow)table.getChildAt(ii);
                tempTrait = user_trait_numbers.get (ii);
                RadioGroup rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                try {
                    tempRadioBtn = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    cmd = String.format("select custom_evaluation_traits_table.id_custom_traitid " +
                            " from custom_evaluation_traits_table " +
                            " where custom_evaluation_traits_table.id_traitid = %s "+
                            " and custom_evaluation_traits_table.custom_evaluation_order =  %s ", tempTrait, tempRadioBtn+1);
                    crsr = dbh.exec( cmd );
                    cursor   = ( Cursor ) crsr;
                    startManagingCursor(cursor);
                    dbh.moveToFirstRecord();                
                    tempRadioBtn = cursor.getInt(0);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    tempRadioBtn = 0;
                }
                user_scores.add(tempRadioBtn);
            }
            for( int ii = nRecs3; ii < 5; ii++ ){   
                user_scores.add(0);
            }
        }else {
            for( int ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++ ){
                user_scores.add(0);
            }
        }
//          Fill the user score variables from the user_scores array
        trait16_data = user_scores.get(0);
        trait17_data = user_scores.get(1);
        trait18_data = user_scores.get(2);
        trait19_data = user_scores.get(3);
        trait20_data = user_scores.get(4);
```

From there I build my query to do the actual update for this sheep record in the sheep_evaluation_table.

Answer (score 0):

maybe its too late but you can just add setoncheckedlistener. this log id and state. after this you use setter and getter.
hope this will help

```
private void inflateRadioButton() {

        ArrayList arrayList = json_helper_class.getChoice_group_multiple();

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(Diagnose_Test_Activity.this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                final RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(Diagnose_Test_Activity.this);

                String a = String.valueOf(arrayList.get(i));
                radioButton.setText(a);
                radioButton.setId(i);

                radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                        String a = String.valueOf(radioButton.getId());

                        Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: "+a+b);
                         //setter here

                    }
                });


                row.addView(radioButton);
            ll_group_multiple_container.addView(row);

        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried that but since I don't want to do anything until I have all the data entered and the user selects the update the database button I couldn't get it to work. It's not like something happens as soon as a radio button is checked. in fact that is exactly what I don't want.  Works for other things though, so thanks.